# Android keyboard stopped working

Tags: cyanogenmod, factory-reset, google-apps

I did a revert from CM10.1 to CM10.

Now, my keyboard is broken. It does not stop crashing. I tried everything:

- Clearing data and cache
- restart of the app
- factory reset
- clearing dalvik and normal cache
- re-installing it several times with different gapps, although I know the correct match.

Now, I'm back to cm-10.0.0-maguro and gapps-jb-20121011-signed. Meanwhile, I'm thinking of a system wipe using CWM recovery. Is this safe, or will it brick my phone? Is there anything I need to know?

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it without a `/system/`-wipe. I reinstalled CM9.1 + gapps, ran it once, and installed CM10 + gapps. Now it works fine! Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

AOSP keyboard crashing in CM is a known issue. I think you can go for a System Wipe. But just go through the precautions you should do.

Try re-flashing your ROM and GAPPS

Comment: Well thats what I did a ton of a times.